# Creating wordcloud using python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, word-cloud

I am trying to create a  **wordcloud** in **python** after cleaning **text file** ,

I got the required results i.e words which are mostly used in the text file but unable to plot.

My code:

```
import collections
from wordcloud import WordCloud
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

file = open('example.txt', encoding = 'utf8' )
stopwords = set(line.strip() for line in open('stopwords'))
wordcount = {}

for word in file.read().split():
    word = word.lower()
    word = word.replace(".","")
    word = word.replace(",","")
    word = word.replace("\"","")
    word = word.replace("“","")
    if word not in stopwords:
        if word not in wordcount:
            wordcount[word] = 1
        else:
            wordcount[word] += 1

d = collections.Counter(wordcount)
for word, count in d.most_common(10):
    print(word , ":", count)

#wordcloud = WordCloud().generate(text)
#fig = plt.figure()
#fig.set_figwidth(14)
#fig.set_figheight(18)

#plt.imshow(wordcloud.recolor(color_func=grey_color, random_state=3))
#plt.title(title, color=fontcolor, size=30, y=1.01)
#plt.annotate(footer, xy=(0, -.025), xycoords='axes fraction', fontsize=infosize, color=fontcolor)
#plt.axis('off')
#plt.show()
```

**Edit**:
Plotted the wordcloud with following **code**:

```
wordcloud = WordCloud(background_color='white',
                          width=1200,
                          height=1000
                         ).generate((d.most_common(10)))


plt.imshow(wordcloud)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

But getting `TypeError: expected string or buffer`

when I tried the above code with `.generate(str(d.most_common(10)))`

The **wordcloud** formed is showing **apostrophe(')** sign after several words

> using Jupyter Notebook | python3 | Ipython

Comment: This is not clear enough. Can you please post just the relevant code and describe the error faced and post the stacktrace of the error?

Comment: Are you open to simpler ways to plot a wordcloud?

Comment: your stopwords is usless use `from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS` then `stopwords = set(STOPWORDS)` ...

Comment: @Rohit select my answer as best answer ? To mark this question resolved ?

Comment: @Coldspeed yes if its working

Comment: @glegoux here I used a separate file which consist of `stopwords` that I want to use

Answer (score 2):

First download this file [Symbola.ttf](https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud/blob/master/examples/fonts/Symbola/Symbola.ttf?raw=true) in the current folder of the following script.

**Architecture file:**

```
file.txt Symbola.ttf my_word_cloud.py
```

**file.txt:**

```
foo buzz bizz foo buzz bizz foo buzz bizz foo buzz bizz foo buzz bizz
foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo bizz bizz bizz bizz foo foo
```

**my_word_cloud.py:**

```
import io
from collections import Counter
from os import path

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from wordcloud import WordCloud

d = path.dirname(__file__)

# It is important to use io.open to correctly load the file as UTF-8
text = io.open(path.join(d, 'file.txt')).read()

words = text.split()
print(Counter(words))

# Generate a word cloud image
# The Symbola font includes most emoji
font_path = path.join(d, 'Symbola.ttf')
word_cloud = WordCloud(font_path=font_path).generate(text)

# Display the generated image:
plt.imshow(word_cloud)
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

Result:

```
Counter({'foo': 17, 'bizz': 9, 'buzz': 5})
```

[image: word cloud]

See a lot of other examples, here I created a simple example for you:

https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud/tree/master/examples

Answer (score -1):

`most_common(x)` is not a method of WordCloud. However, you can pass the parameter

```
max_words =
```

and this should do what you're attempting.